# Why are none of my layout files being found in my Android project?

Tags: android, xml

I am using Android studio and none of my layout files used in my classes are being found. I know the problem is most likely somewhere in my xml but cannot find the problem. I suspect the problem may be in my styles xml so I have included that code.

When I try to build or run the project I gent the error message "cannot find symbol variable: main_menu...etc etc"

Here is my xml:

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

    <permission
          android:name="com.example.daniel.multiplepalerts.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.daniel.multiplepalerts.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>   

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxx"/>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.daniel.multiplepalerts.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ProximityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.daniel.multiplepalerts"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
                </intent-filter>

        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_Main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.daniel.multiplepalerts.MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**V21/Styles**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Styles**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Menu_Main**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Your V21/Styles has a double `>>` on the first line. Is that a typo in this post? If not, then this might cause the `R` class fail to be generated.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that typo in V21Styles but still have the errors.

Comment: At the moment the R class is being generated its just that all the layout files in the code that follow "R.layout_file_name" causing cannot find symbol variable errors.

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Just to make sure: you have your `main_activity.xml` in the correct layout folder and you are trying to access it with `R.layout.main_activity`?

Comment: Yes I have tried clean and rebuild, invalidate caches and restart, as well as restarting Android Stuidio.

Comment: I have also checked the activity_main is in the correct folder and trying to access it with R.layout.activity_main.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. One of my classes contained the line import android.R; so removing this solved the errors.